# how to read a text file in python and output variables into a csv

Tags: python, forms, csv, email

I made a website and whenever someone sends a form (e.g. inquire about my work) I get an email so I'm trying to automate this I have got as far as to download relevant emails and cut out irrelevant data but I'm stuck on how to import the .txt file and export it into a spreadsheet (.csv file) this is the .txt file I'm trying to extract the data from:

`

```
Name:
someone

Email:
someone@gmail.com

Site: someone.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name:
someone51

Email:
someone1@gmail.com


Site: someone1.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.2

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Name:
someone

Email:
someone52@gmail.com

Site: someone.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.5

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name:
someone51

Email:
someone52532222@gmail.com


Site: someone1.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.76

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Name:
someone123

Email:
someone123@gmail.com

Site: someone.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.21

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name:
someone51

Email:
someone1@gmail.com


Site: someone1.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.2

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`
obviously, I had to change the exact data but this is the layout I have got it too.

So I am asking about how I can change this .txt file and put it systematically into a spreadsheet

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the question that you have?

Comment: I have updated the question so I am asking about how I can change this .txt file and put it systematically into a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

If we just take a section of the file, it will make working with it much easier:

```
f = """Name: someone    
Email: someone@gmail.com    
Site: someone.com    
Remote IP: 192.168.0.1"""
```

So, assuming you know how to open the file into Python, you should have a multi-line string like above.

Now, if we can safely say that a colon (`:`) splits the two columns in each line, then all we have to do is *`replace`* all of them with commas and output this new string to a file. Simple as that.

To do this, we do not need to iterate over the string, we can just use the `str.replace` method to replace them all in one go:

```
f = f.replace(":", ",")
```

and then `f` will be modified to a `CSV` format:

```
Name, someone    
Email, someone@gmail.com    
Site, someone.com    
Remote IP, 192.168.0.1
```

Now, all that is left to do is write this data to a file that ends in `.csv`:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as of:
    of.write(f)
```

And that's it! You can now open `output.csv` in any `CSV` viewer and it should read the file!

---

Here is a screenshot of what it looked like for me, after opening in `LibreOffice`:

[image: table]

so it seems to have worked!

---

**update**

So, there are `2` problems to solve for the above solution to work:

- how to read the file
- how to join lines that overlap to the next line

To read the file (into a variable: `f`) there are *many, many* tutorials so I won't go into any depth. But essentially, just do:

```
f = open("input.txt").read()
```

---

Then, if we are now dealing with `f` as possibly something like:

```
Name:
someone

Email:
someone@gmail.com

Site: someone.com

Remote IP: 192.168.0.1
```

Then we need to replace the occurrences of `:\n` with just `:` to remove the overflowing lines. We also need to remove any double lines by replacing `\n\n` with just `\n`.

Those `2` operations can be done in one line:

```
f = f.replace(":\n", ":").replace("\n\n", "\n")
```

Then, we can just use the same steps as outlined at the start of the answer to write the data to a `CSV` file.

---

*Note that at this stage, you may want to look into using `re.sub` as that would simplify the code a bit!*

Comment: but some name is in the file as  name : <in another line> james and how will I extract the multi line string from the file

Comment: can you just point me in the right direction to import those lines into the variable.Thanks much appreciated

Comment: @Tufayl It's in the answer! Just do: `f = open("input.txt").read()`

Comment: but that will read the whole file son how will I separate the columns

Comment: Read the answer! You need to read in the whole file, and then replace the colons with commas - which are recognised by a `CSV` file reader to *mean* columns!

Comment: But how will I differentiate the rows? Thanks

Comment: The rows are each line in the file after applying the replacements after the "**update**"

Comment: but i want the csv file to look like the columns to be email - site - ip and the rows to be the name

Comment: @Tufayl I **finally** see what you want! Very confusing :p I will see what I can do tomorrow - you should have been clearer in your explanation though really.

Comment: Sorry, Thank you though

Comment: can you please help me because I am stuck and I would really appreciate the help.Thanks